# Django: order by multi-level reverse look up

Tags: django, foreign-keys, sql-order-by, django-queryset

Django: order by multi-level reverse look up

I have following 3 models

```
class Product(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(
        blank=False,
        max_length=256
    )


class TaskGroup(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(
        blank=False,
        max_length=256
    )

    product = models.ForeignKey(
        Product,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        null=False,
        blank=True
    )


class Task(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(
        blank=False,
        max_length=256
    )

    task_group = models.ForeignKey(
        TaskGroup,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        null=False,
        blank=True
    )
    
    execute_at = models.DateField(
        blank=True
        null=True,
    )
```

I want to get all the `Products` ordered by the `execute_at` date of `Task`. How can I do this?
Is it possible to do this using a single query?

There can be multiple tasks for a product. But always consider the smaller `execute_at` date i.e
the date that is closest to current date.

Comment: What if there are *multiple* `Task`?

Comment: Your `Task` model has furthermore no `created_at` date field?

Comment: Please check the update

Comment: that's not the smallest, but the largest, since as time progresses, the timestamp increases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can [**`.annotate(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#annotate) by the maximum of the `created_at` field, and then order with:

```
from django.db.models import Max

Products.objects.annotate(
    last_task=Max('taskgroup__task__execute_at')
).order_by('-last_task')
```

You can order items with no related `Task` at the end with:

```
from django.db.models import F, Max

Products.objects.annotate(
    last_task=Max('taskgroup__task__execute_at')
).order_by(F('last_task').desc(nulls_last=True))
```

Comment: Your  query is correct but is there a way to order the product with no task to be at the end? But if there are any task then the product with lowest task `execute_at` should show  first.

Comment: @StaticName: the lowest? Bit that means the "oldest". Note that the timestamp increases in time. But you can use `nulls_last=True` to set the items with no related `Task` as last, see edit.